# Read values from style tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a style tag in my html document what looks like that:

```
<style>
     #workspace a:not(.notClickable){color:#c75858 !important; text-decoration: underline; !important;} 
     #workspace a:not(.notClickable):hover {color:#c75a1b2 !important; text-decoration: none; !important;}
</style>
```

How can I read values:

```
color:#c75858

text-decoration: underline

color:#c75a1b2

text-decoration: none
```

into variables using jQuery?

Comment: Use `document.styleSheets`. There's no jQuery function for it, you have to use plain Javascript.

Comment: `$('#wokspace a').attr('css':'#c75858');` use this....etc